# Kafka Containers Integration test, autowired Consumer doesn't start

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I tested the application locally with a Kafka set up, and the consumers starts and listen to the local Kafka topic, and call a service when a message is consumed.

I'm trying to reproduce and test the behaviour in an integration test, but the consumer fails to start during the integration test. This problem happens with both the @EmbbededKafka set up, or with the usage of Kafka testcontainers.

I know the configuration, the name of the topic, group id and ports are properly sets due to some debugging.

Since I don't really have more context to provide, here is some relevant code about the integration class:

```
@Testcontainers
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = SqlContainerConfiguration.class, classes = {
    KafkaConsumerConfiguration.class,
    KafkaProducerConfiguration.class,
    KafkaListenerService.class
})
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestOrchestratorApplication.class, KafkaConsumerConfiguration.class},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import({KafkaProducerConfiguration.class, KafkaConsumerConfiguration.class, KafkaListenerService.class})
@DirtiesContext
public class KafkaIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private KafkaProducerConfiguration kafkaProducerConfiguration;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaConsumerConfiguration kafkaConsumerConfiguration;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaListenerService kafkaListenerService;

// some mocked API and Interfaces

  private static final String TEST_TOPIC = “test-topic";

  @Container
  private static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer("5.5.0")
                                                     .withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "true");

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void kafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    List<String> env = new ArrayList<>();
    env.add("KAFKA_LISTENERS=" + kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
    env.add("KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=" + "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093");
    env.add("KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=" + kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
    kafkaContainer.setEnv(env);
    kafkaContainer.setEnv(env);
    // Start the container
    kafkaContainer.start();
    String bootstrapServers = kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers();
    // Remove the "PLAINTEXT://" prefix if present
    if (bootstrapServers.startsWith("PLAINTEXT://")) {
      bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers.substring("PLAINTEXT://".length());
    }

    // Configure the bootstrap servers for the consumer and producer
    String finalBootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
    registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", () -> finalBootstrapServers);
    String finalBootstrapServers1 = bootstrapServers;
    registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", () -> finalBootstrapServers1);
  }

@Test
public void testKafkaIntegration() throws Exception {
  KafkaTemplate<String, UserEvent> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(kafkaProducerConfiguration.producerFactory());

// Mock method
   when(methodToBeMocked)…

  // Send the message to the Kafka topic
  ListenableFuture<?> sendResult = kafkaTemplate.send(TEST_TOPIC, aMessageToBeSend);

  // Wait for the message to be sent
  sendResult.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  // Wait for the listener to be invoked
  latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  System.out.println(kafkaContainer.getLogs());
  if (sendResult.isDone() && !sendResult.isCancelled()) {
// verify mock has been called
    verify(methodToBeMocked)…..;
  } else {
    fail("Failed to send message");
  }
}
```

In this case, not only the service method isn't called, but in the kafka logs, there is not trace of the consumer, so it seems it is not even started.

In the application, I have a KafkaConsumerConfiguration class, which is autowired, and by debugging I can confirm that the KafkaConsumerConfiguration Bean is called.

Here is the consumer configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfiguration {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerConfiguration.class);

  @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  @Value("${spring.kafka.group-id}")
  private String groupId;

  private final Map<String, Object> consumerConfig;

  public KafkaConsumerConfiguration(
      @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers,
      @Value("${spring.kafka.group-id}") String groupId
  ) {
    this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
    this.groupId = groupId;

    consumerConfig = Map.of(
        ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers,
        ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId,
        ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest",
        ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keyDeserializer,
        ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueDeserializer
    );
  }

  public static final Class<StringDeserializer> keyDeserializer = StringDeserializer.class;
  public static final Class<JsonDeserializer> valueDeserializer = JsonDeserializer.class;

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, UserEvent> consumerFactory() {
    logger.info("Creating Consumer Factory with Configuration: {}", consumerConfig);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>());
  }

  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, UserEvent>> factory(
      ConsumerFactory<String, UserEvent> consumerFactory
  ) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, UserEvent> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
  }

  public void setBootstrapServers(String bootstrapServers) {
    this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
  }

  public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getConsumerConfig() {
    return consumerConfig;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that includes your consumer code since what you've shown is only a producer and some unknown mock... Kafka already has MockConsumer class that will not connect to a running broker

Comment: I added the KafkaConsumerConfiguration class.

Comment: Spring Boot automatically creates the correct configuration classes with `@Configuration` annotation. You do not need your own classes https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka And EmbeddedBroker should work as well https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#ktu